# macから、vagrantのcentosをproxyにして、vagrant上に作ったdockerのコンテナにSSHしたい

Tags: vagrant, docker, ssh

お世話になります

dockerを試して見たく、さらに、SSHプロキシを試してみたく、いま調べております
そこで以下のサイトを参考にしました
[MacからSSH接続可能なDockerコンテナを作る。 - Less is Best](http://yss44.hatenablog.com/entry/2014/01/02/083600)

現状ですが、vagrantのCentOS内で、Dockerfileを使ってbuildするところで、最後にこけています

```
sudo docker build -t "shiratsu/docker_sshd" .

2015/01/27 02:21:48 Unknown filesystem type on /dev/mapper/docker-253:0-17040161-9e50380ebda65fe7f1061951d8a9448ef2fda5807957caf1faef9c72e68b4774
```

色々調べてはいるものの、解決はせずでして。。。

ちなみに、dockerの情報は以下です

```
[shiratsu@localhost ~]$ sudo docker info
Containers: 1
Images: 5
Storage Driver: devicemapper
Pool Name: docker-253:0-17040161-pool
Pool Blocksize: 65.54 kB
Data file: /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/devicemapper/data
Metadata file: /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/devicemapper/metadata
Data Space Used: 89.19 MB
Data Space Total: 107.4 GB
Metadata Space Used: 1.192 MB
Metadata Space Total: 2.147 GB
Library Version: 1.02.89-RHEL6 (2014-09-01)
Execution Driver: native-0.2
Kernel Version: 2.6.32-358.el6.x86_64
Operating System: <unknown>
```

OSがunknownなのも気になりますが。。。

その他OS情報はこちらです

```
[shiratsu@localhost ~]$ uname -a
Linux localhost.localdomain 2.6.32-358.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Feb 22 00:31:26 UTC        2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
[shiratsu@localhost ~]$ df -h
 Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% マウント位置
 /dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_root
                  490G  1.7G  463G   1% /
 tmpfs                 230M     0  230M   0% /dev/shm
 /dev/sda1             485M   32M  429M   7% /boot
 [shiratsu@localhost ~]$
```

ちなみにDockerfileはこちらです（編集しました。以下はうまくいった、Dockerfileです）

```
[shiratsu@localhost ~]$ cat docker/Dockerfile
# SSH-DOCKER
#
# VERSION       1

FROM centos:centos6

MAINTAINER shiratsu

RUN yum -y update

#Dev tools for all Docker
RUN yum -y install git vim

RUN yum -y install passwd openssh openssh-server openssh-clients sudo


# create user

RUN useradd shiratsu
RUN passwd -f -u shiratsu
RUN mkdir -p /home/shiratsu/.ssh;chown shiratsu /home/shiratsu/.ssh; chmod 700  /home/shiratsu/.ssh
ADD ./authorized_keys /home/shiratsu/.ssh/authorized_keys
RUN chown shiratsu /home/shiratsu/.ssh/authorized_keys;chmod 600       /home/shiratsu/.ssh/authorized_keys

# setup sudoers
RUN echo "shiratsu ALL=(ALL) ALL" >> /etc/sudoers.d/shiratsu

# setup sshd
ADD ./sshd_config /etc/ssh/sshd_config
RUN /etc/init.d/sshd start;/etc/init.d/sshd stop

# expose for sshd
EXPOSE 2222

CMD ["/usr/sbin/sshd","-D"]
```

vagrant内のcentosとdockerのバージョン追記します

```
[shiratsu@localhost ~]$ sudo docker version
Client version: 1.3.2
Client API version: 1.15
Go version (client): go1.3.3
Git commit (client): 39fa2fa/1.3.2
OS/Arch (client): linux/amd64
Server version: 1.3.2
Server API version: 1.15
Go version (server): go1.3.3
Git commit (server): 39fa2fa/1.3.2
[shiratsu@localhost ~]$ cat /etc/redhat-release
CentOS release 6.4 (Final)
```

以下の形で終わってます

```
[shiratsu@localhost docker]$ sudo docker build -t "shiratsu/docker_sshd" .

Step 3 : RUN yum -y install git vim
---> Running in 83559dba7226 

省略

Complete!
2015/01/27 05:26:50 Unknown filesystem type on /dev/mapper/docker-253:0-    17040527-5acf57c684f52d4890db5239ca86fd39fc91f2804f4f38d75f526570b7517e42
```

最小限に一旦変更

```
[shiratsu@localhost docker]$ sudo docker build -t "shiratsu/docker_sshd" .
Sending build context to Docker daemon 6.656 kB
Sending build context to Docker daemon
Step 0 : FROM busybox
Pulling repository busybox
4986bf8c1536: Download complete
511136ea3c5a: Download complete
df7546f9f060: Download complete
ea13149945cb: Download complete
Status: Downloaded newer image for busybox:latest
 ---> 4986bf8c1536
Step 1 : RUN echo hello world
 ---> Running in 59bd215b5aee
hello world
 ---> 9eb80f3639b9
Removing intermediate container 59bd215b5aee
Successfully built 9eb80f3639b9

[shiratsu@localhost docker]$ sudo docker images
REPOSITORY             TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED                  VIRTUAL SIZE
shiratsu/docker_sshd   latest              9eb80f3639b9        About a minute ago   2.433 MB
busybox                buildroot-2014.02   4986bf8c1536        3 weeks ago          2.433 MB
busybox                latest              4986bf8c1536        3 weeks ago          2.433 MB
```

作ったのち、Dockerのコンテナに対してSSHできることを確認した。

```
[shiratsu@localhost ~]$ ssh -p 2222 -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa shiratsu@172.17.0.11
Enter passphrase for key '/home/shiratsu/.ssh/id_rsa':
Last login: Wed Jan 28 02:31:40 2015 from 172.17.42.1
[shiratsu@b4ec26bb342c ~]$
```

最後にローカルMacから接続できるか確認！

```
{15-01-28 11:54}[ruby-2.1.0]server:~@master✗✗✗✗✗✗ shiratsu% ssh -v -o ProxyCommand='nc -x 192.168.33.10 %h %p' -p 2222 -i /Users/shiratsu/.ssh/id_rsa 172.17.0.11
OpenSSH_6.2p2, OSSLShim 0.9.8r 8 Dec 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/shiratsu/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 53: Applying options for *
debug1: Executing proxy command: exec nc -x 192.168.33.10 172.17.0.11 2222
debug1: permanently_drop_suid: 501
debug1: identity file /Users/shiratsu/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /Users/shiratsu/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.2
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

docker側のhosts.allow,hosts.denyに何も設定はなかったです
他になにかこのSSHできない問題に何か回答ありますでしょうか

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: たびたびすみません。試しに`RUN /etc/init.d/sshd..`の行をコメントアウトされますと、状況は改善しますか？（手元のCentOS6.5@Vagrant@Yosemiteでは正常終了しました）
CentOS7ではsystemdに移行しているので怪しいなと思った次第です。尚、コメントアウトしない場合、単にcommand not foundエラーが返ってきて、質問内容にあるようなエラーではありませんでした。。

Comment: ログを少しよく見てみたところ、そもそも。以下が終了後に次に進んでいなかったです
{RUN yum -y install git vim}

ログは上に一部追記します。

Comment: エラーメッセージから https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/4036 というイシューを見つけましたが、関連があるかどうかまではわかりません。試しに`FROM busybox
RUN  echo hello world`(RUN前で改行)といった最小限のDockerfileでビルドが成功するか確認していただくことは可能ですか？

Comment: ビルドできました。追記します。

Comment: つまりはDockerfileに問題がありということですか？

Comment: Dockerfileにも動かないであろう部分はあります(/etc/init.d/sshdの箇所）が、今回のエラー内容は別の原因だと考えています。手元のvagrant上にあるCentOS6.5およびUbuntu14.04では https://gist.github.com/3100/feda22d6bd5ea565aea2 のように返ってきます。
docker周りの問題かもしれませんが、可能性としてはvagrant側の設定が影響しているという線もあり得るように思いました。

Comment: なるほどです。ちょっとcentosのバージョンを一つ上に上げて試してみます

Comment: こちらは6.4で試してみます。それで依然として再現できない場合、手順を「回答」の箇所に残しておこうと思います。。

Comment: 原因はさっぱり解らないので回答は出来ないのですが、 `sudo service docker stop` して `sudo mv /var/lib/docker /tmp/` とかして `sudo service docker start` してから、`sudo docker build ...` 的なことをしてみるとどうでしょう

Comment: @ohgaさん　一応上記に近いことを試してるのですが、だめでした
sudo mv /var/lib/docker /tmp/
をmvではなく、rmしてるだけです

Comment: ざんねんです。。こうなると docker というより、OS とか vagrant ですかね。。

Comment: 解決されたようで良かったです。後から見る方に役立つ質問となるために、質問文をまとめ、不要となったコメント(質問文に反映済みのもの)を整理されても良いかもしれません。
また、解決した部分については、ご自身で回答して、その後解答としてチェックされると良いかとおもいます。

Comment: @3100さん　了解いたしました。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MacのローカルからSSHする部分ですが、解決しました。
単純に書き方（通信の書き方）に問題がありました

```
{15-01-28 12:22}[ruby-2.1.0]server:~@master✗✗✗✗✗✗ shiratsu% ssh -o      ProxyCommand='ssh 192.168.33.10 nc %h %p' -p 2222 172.17.0.11
The authenticity of host '[172.17.0.11]:2222 (<no hostip for proxy command>)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is 0e:af:56:90:5a:87:17:d7:9d:0e:d6:d8:48:88:24:a1.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added '[172.17.0.11]:2222' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
Last login: Wed Jan 28 02:40:50 2015 from 172.17.42.1
[shiratsu@b4ec26bb342c ~]$
```

Answer (score 1):

(質問に対する解決はしていないので、他の方のより良い回答を待ちましょう。解答としてのマークは不要です)

`Unknown filesystem type ..`のエラーは再現できませんでしたが、逆に正しく動作する`docker`環境を構築するのに役立つかもしれませんので、手元で試した構築手順を掲載いたします。

- VirtualBox 4.3.20 r96996
- vagrant 1.7.2
- ruby 2.2.0-p0
- OSX 10.10.1

の環境で`CentOS 6.4`の仮想環境から`docker build`するまでです。

```
$ vagrant box add https://github.com/2creatives/vagrant-centos/releases/download/v6.4.2/centos64-x86_64-20140116.box --name centos64
$ mkdir ~/centos64
$ cd ~/centos64
$ vagrant init
```

イメージ用boxファイルは http://www.vagrantbox.es/ にあるものを利用しました。

`Vagrantfile`内で

```
config.vm.box = "centos64"
```

としておきます。

```
$ vagrant up
$ vagrant ssh
```

でCentOS6.4にログインします。

```
$ sudo su
# rpm -ivh http://ftp.jaist.ac.jp/pub/Linux/Fedora/epel/6/i386/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
# yum -y install docker-io
# service docker start
# chkconfig docker on
# mkdir docker
# cd docker
```

ここで質問に書かれている`Dockerfile`をそのままコピペして保存。また、`ADD`を満たすために空ファイルを作成しておきます。(本来は適したファイルを置きます）

```
# touch authorized_keys
# touch sshd_config
# vi Dockerfile
```

あとはbuildを試行。

```
# docker build -t "hoge/docker_sshd" .
```

で無事ビルドが完了しました。

`docker`のバージョンは

```
# docker -v
docker version 1.3.2, build 39fa2fa/1.3.2
```

でした。

---

もし当初の`Dockerfile`にあったように`CentOS7`を利用したい場合では`/etc/init.d/`ではなく`systemctl`を使うことになります。以下に参考リンクを載せて置きます。

[CentOS 7のDockerコンテナ内でsystemdを使ってサービスを起動する - Qiita](http://qiita.com/yunano/items/9637ee21a71eba197345)

Comment: centos6.5にしたら、同じところまでたどり着きました

Comment: DockerfileのインストールするOSをcentosにしたら、うまくいきました。
centos7で変わってしまうので、7で作る場合は、気をつけないといけないですね。
一応Dockerfileは変えておきます
また、centos7でも試してみます。
うまくいったら、また報告します

Comment: centos6を指定するのが良さそうですね。後ほど、更新されたDockerfileの結果に更新します。

Comment: 問題なくビルドが完了したので、Centos7のビルド失敗の部分を消しておきました。